# facing issue in animation while reloading its working but normally while scrolling its not working

Tags: javascript, html

Facing issue in animation while reloading its working but normally while scrolling its not working. I want to add this section twice in a page every time when I scroll I need the animation to work

```
    <div class="content"></div>

    <div class="about hidden">
        <h2>header</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo dolor, similique ea molestiae earum quas 
           sint accusantium itaque magnam laborum laboriosam, expedita qui nihil dicta soluta exercitationem quos
           iste. Quam.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content"></div>

    <script>

     (function(){
       var aboutEl= $('div.about'),
           aboutEloffset=aboutEl.offset().top/2,
           documentEl= $(document);

        documentEl.on('scroll',function(){
             if(documentEl.scrollTop() >aboutEloffset &&  aboutEl.hasClass('hidden'))aboutEl.removeClass('hidden');
        });


     })();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to explain what isn't working by adding the behavior or errors you are getting and describing the behavior you want.